# How to calculate textarea given values in JS

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to calculate the values that are in my input boxes that's in the middle of the webpage. I thought if i add the class names references in JS within a function that i would get the results or atleast no error messages but now it says "calculate is not defined
at addTotal
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick"

What i am trying to do is Multiply the values by the numbers that's assigns to the boxes and then display the total below the button.

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="wrapper">
  <textarea name="Buy" id="advertise" cols="55" rows="50"></textarea>

  <div id="textFields">
    <textarea name="" class="center calculate" cols="100" rows="5"></textarea>
    <textarea name="" class="center calculate2" cols="100" rows="5"></textarea>
    <textarea name="" class="center calculate3" cols="100" rows="5"></textarea>
    <div class="buttonClass">
        <button class="addTotalButton" onclick="addTotal()">Add Total</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>


body {
    background-color: #434343;
  }
  
  #textFields {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  
  .center {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 100px;
  }
  
  .wrapper {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }

  /* #inputButton {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: #011526;
    color: aliceblue;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
    flex-basis: 50%;
     
  } */

  .buttonClass {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      
  }

  .addTotalButton {
      margin-top: 50px;
  }

let addTotal = ()=> {
    let answerElement = document.getElementsByClassName("calculate")
     answerElement.innerHTML = parseInt(addTotal) * 20;

     let quoteElement = document.getElementsByClassName("calculate2")
           quoteElement.innerHTML = parseInt(addTotal) * 30;

           let timesElement = document.getElementsByClassName("calculate3")
                   timesElement.innerHTML = parseInt(addTotal) * 50;
                    
                   return calculate + calculate2 + calculate3;


}
```

Comment: Maybe use the `script` tag?

Comment: @natre214 The JS file is external, i'm trying to figure out how to correctly calculate the given values that will be inputted inside the text areas.

Comment: Ah ok, I see ;)

Comment: Have you checked the documentation for `getElementsByClassName`? It's relevant.

Comment: variable calculate is not defined in your script. what do you expect inside calculate ?

Comment: I haven't check the rest of the code but if this "document.getElementsByClassName" works it gives you array for sure.

Comment: @jeremy-denis basically when i add a number inside that textarea that has the class name calculate i want the number to be multiplied by 20

Comment: ok one  last question for me. Why use textarea (that can be multi line) and not input with a type number ? What happen if i write several number in text area separated by space or coma ?

Comment: @traktor going to go give it a read. Thanks for the response

Comment: @jeremy-denis that's a good question, so Textarea wasn't the way to go. i should have used input? my apologies im new to coding and this HW is kinda frustrating lol

Comment: @Samich Thanks for the great response! I will continue to figure this out based on your response.

Comment: @jeremy-denis Thanks for the amazing responses! I've learned a lot with your edits and descriptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can change several point in your code

1. use input with type number instead of textarea (you will be able to use element.value to get the value)
2. `document.getElementsByClassName` return an array if you just want one element you can access it by index or use `querySelector` that return you the first element match selector
3. your function add Total do nothing if you want to set the value of main text area you can use element.value

```js
let addTotal = ()=> {
    let answerElement = document.querySelector(".calculate");
    let calculate = parseInt(answerElement.value) * 20;
    
    let quoteElement = document.querySelector(".calculate2");
    let calculate2 = parseInt(quoteElement.value) * 20;
    
    let timesElement = document.querySelector(".calculate2");
    let calculate3 = parseInt(timesElement.value) * 20;
    
    console.log(calculate + calculate2 + calculate3);
    document.getElementById('advertise').value = calculate + calculate2 + calculate3;
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #434343;
  }
  
  #textFields {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  
  .center {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 100px;
  }
  
  .wrapper {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }

  /* #inputButton {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: #011526;
    color: aliceblue;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
    flex-basis: 50%;
     
  } */

  .buttonClass {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      
  }

  .addTotalButton {
      margin-top: 50px;
  }
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="wrapper">
  <textarea name="Buy" id="advertise" cols="55" rows="50"></textarea>

  <div id="textFields">
    <input type="number" class="center calculate"/>
    <input type="number" class="center calculate2"/>
    <input type="number" class="center calculate3"/>
    <div class="buttonClass">
        <button class="addTotalButton" onclick="addTotal()">Add Total</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: woooooow i totally forgot about console log smh!!! also i need to read up on document.queryselector i thought getelement by classname would have gotten the result i desire.